# Is it possible to use multiple callbacks in the WindowButtonMotionFcn?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, event-handling

I created a class which adds functionality to a figure on construction. This class creates a listener for the `WindowMouseMotion` event; however, to get this event to fire I had to add a dummy callback function for the figure's `WindowButtonMotionFcn` property. I first check if this property is already populated. If it isn't then I set it to a dummy callback function that does nothing.

Instead of checking if the property is already set or not, can I simply add this dummy callback to any existing callbacks? Is it possible for a callback property to call multiple functions?

**EDIT**

When using the `handle.listener` approach to handle the `WindowButtonMotionEvent` event given below, be sure to use `eventdata.CurrentPoint` to access the current mouse position. The `CurrentPoint` property of the figure does not get updated before handling the `WindowButtonMotionEvent` event in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A related article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/inactive-control-tooltips-event-chaining/) can be found on Yair Altman's Undocumented MATLAB blog, from guest blogger Matt Whitaker. What you are alluding to is *callback chaining*, and quoting from the blog:

> Frankly, having written code
>   previously that handles callback
>   chaining, I would rather poke myself
>   in the eye with a fork!

Luckily, there appears to be an alternative solution in that article. Using a snippet from the code posted there, I was able to get a function to execute on mouse movement *without* having to set the `'WindowButtonMotionFcn'`. I added a listener to the current figure like so:

```
myListener = handle.listener(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionEvent',...
                             @(hSource,eventData) disp('hello'));
```

And the message `hello` was displayed when I moved the mouse in the window.

Comment: Be sure to use `eventdata.CurrentPoint` to access the current mouse position when using the above approach. The `CurrentPoint` property of the figure does not get updated before handling the `WindowButtonMotionEvent` event in this manner.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, but solves the problem that prompted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via cellfun and feval, as answered on Mathworks site: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10664-multiple-callback-functions

```
obj = uicontrol(...,'style','popupmenu',...
  'Callback', @(h,e)(cellfun(@(x)feval(x,h,e), ...
   {@(h,e)this.myfunc(h), ...
   @(h,e)this.myfunc2(h), ...
   @(h,e)this.myfunc2(h)}))
```

Note that the callback is set to an anonymous function using cellfun to evaluate each handler.