# Getting Matlab handles events or properties

Tags: matlab, user-interface, reflection, event-handling, handle

### The question

*How may I get the list of events and properties for a handle of double type, as a `figure`, `axes`?*

### The issue

Matlab documentation says to you to use the `WindowButtonDownFcn`, `WindowButtonMotionFcn`, and so on in order to listen to whatever happens at your interface. The issue is that this properties are very limited as [the following fact](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011b/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-55506.html?searchHighlight=function%20handle%20callbacks):

**Keeping Variables in Scope**

> When MATLAB evaluates function handles, **the same variables are in
>   scope as when the function handle was created.** (In contrast, callbacks
>   specified as strings are evaluated in the base workspace.) **This
>   simplifies the process of managing global data, such as object
>   handles, in a GUI.**

Yes, this is perfect, **if you don't have to redefine, add, or remove callbacks from your ButtonDownFcn**, because if you do so, you will lose the other function handles variable scopes, as you are declaring them at a new scope which <s>may</s> will certainly not contain your so needed variables.

So one way would be to listen to the events themselves, not to properties that are called when the events are actived, and by doing so, you will not have to bother to redeclare your ButtonDownFcn and how to keep your variables at scope, because the other solutions are **very slow to implement!**. If I could listen to the events directly, as I do with `handle.listener` or `addlistener` matlab listening tools, I would not have to bother with that.

### One good approach already known

One of the best solutions it seems is [this FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34728-graphical-wrappers), which empowers the weak matlab `WindowButtonDownFcn`, `WindowButtonDownFcn` and whatever properties "listeners" function matlab has, so that you can have any amounts of functions listening to changes at the your graphical interface without having to care if your other functions handles will lose their scope variables.

With this I don't need to get the matlab events as it wrappers everything for me. But it still amuses me that matlab lead your users to use a broken feature instead of documenting the better approach and lead people to wrap everything around so that they can use things as they should be.

---

### Information that may be useful.

I know about the [`meta.class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) that will give me all the properties, events and so on that a class have. For one class I have that inherits from a `handle`:

```
>> EventMeta = ?Event
EventMeta = 

  class with properties:

                     Name: 'Event'
              Description: ''
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 1
          InferiorClasses: {0x1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: []
             PropertyList: [64x1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [29x1 meta.method]
                EventList: [2x1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0x1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [1x1 meta.class]
```

with that meta I can get the EventList from my `Event` class, which are:

```
>> EventMeta.EventList.Name

ans =

attemptToClick


ans =

ObjectBeingDestroyed
```

Well, this is not that great thing in this case, since I have implemented it and I know the events it has because I have the source. The thing is, if I can get the metaclass of a `figure` (if that is possible), I could have access to its implemented `Events` if they are available at the matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, [Handle Graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) (HG) are implemented using the undocumented [UDD](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/creating-a-simple-udd-class/) mechanism, not the usual `classdef`-style OOP exposed to the user.

That's why you cant directly use the `meta.class` system to get meta-information on such handles.

As you already found out on [Yair Altman's blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/udd-events-and-listeners/), there are undocumented ways to listen to events:

```
fig = hg.figure(); plot(rand(100,1))
lh = handle.listener(fig, 'WindowButtonDownEvent',@(~,~)disp('clicked'));
```

If you already have an existing HG object handle (represented with a numeric handle), use `handle` to convert it to a UDD handle:

```
f = figure();
fig = handle(f);
```

and yes I know, the term `handle` is quite overloaded in MATLAB and may refer to many things

Comment: In fact, I was going to post that the HG2 will use one `meta.class` compatible approach. I think matlab is not trying to improve the handle graphics mechanism because they are substituting it for a new one. Everything makes sense now, the why it is everything so messy when using the handle graphics. I hope they document the HG2 properly, at least with the `meta.class` access it gets quite easier.

Comment: @Werner: yes [HG2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/) is supposed to be the next big thing, but I doubt the upgrade will happen any time soon. The current HG system has been around for a long time, with a lot of legacy attached to it...

Comment: another related blog post: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/property-value-change-listeners

Answer (score 2):

As I was improving my question, I managed to find an answer for this (unfortunately it seems that I haven't seem them before at my searchs, and what's worse, some of the links I've opened before…)

Here the [undocummented matlab blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/inactive-control-tooltips-event-chaining/) shows how to get the handles from a matlab handle object. And it seems that there was already a question about this made at 2011 about this issue [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116969/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-callbacks-in-the-windowbuttonmotionfcn), and properly answered by @gnovice. The answer is:

```
>> get(get(classhandle(handle(gcf)),'Events'),'Name')
ans = 
    'SerializeEvent'
    'FigureUpdateEvent'
    'ResizeEvent'
    'WindowKeyReleaseEvent'
    'WindowKeyPressEvent'
    'WindowButtonUpEvent'
    'WindowButtonDownEvent'
    'WindowButtonMotionEvent'
    'WindowPostChangeEvent'
    'WindowPreChangeEvent'
```

I still would like to call your attention to the [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34728-graphical-wrappers) as another good solution that may give you better possibilities for working with the graphical components offered by matlab.

Usage example:

```
>> k=handle.listener(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionEvent','disp(''MOVEMENT DETECTED!!'')');   
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!! % When you move the mouse on the figure
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!!
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!!
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!!
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!!
>> MOVEMENT DETECTED!!
>> delete(k)
```

Comment: Just discovered several nice things about this!! May post it when I have some time. Now it makes sense why everything was soooo messy…

Answer (score 1):

Try using get:

```
fig = gcf();
get(fig)
```

Comment: Yeah, this give me the properties, I know, but that wont give me the events x(

Comment: By events, do you mean the functions that are executed upon sum action? These are listed as properties, usually with the suffix "Fcn".

Comment: Dont forget the `@`. The 'Fcn' are properties, not the triggered events that are thrown with a `notify` and may be listeners by a `handle.listener` object or by using the `addlistener` function (which will create a `handle.listener` and add it to the matlab listeners stack. The Fcn properties are VERY limited when you have several places modifying the Fcn property…

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this.  I can provide some sample code to demonstrate what I think is being asked.  This is a relatively new (therefore unused) Matlab feature:

```
hh = handle(gca);
lsnr = addlistener(hh,'XLim','PreGet',@(~,~)disp('<<<Getting XLIM values>>>'))
```

To see the listener in action

```
>> get(hh,'XLim')
<<<Getting XLIM values>>>
ans =
     0     1
```

I think the question is how to get `lsnr` from `gca` if the value was not stored.

I can't find a way.

Comment: BTW, if this is a correct interpretation, you should add the code to the original question.

Comment: thank you, but I think my question was not that clear. I'll edit it soon with more information.