# MATLAB: I am having trouble with a callback function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, uicontrol

i have written a code which creates a figure with 3 buttons and a text box. the program complains about my callback function when i press a button though.

```
function game(states)

fig=figure('position',[200 150 500 370]);
face.B1=uicontrol('parent',fig,'style','pushbutton','string','start!','visible','on','position',[20 160 460 50]);
face.B2=uicontrol('style','pushbutton','parent',fig,'string','B2','visible','off','position',[20 90 460 50]);
face.B3=uicontrol('style','pushbutton','parent',fig,'string','B3','visible','off','position',[20 20 460 50]);
face.txtbx=uicontrol('style','text','parent',fig,'string','welcome to my game. press start to begin','position',[20 230 460 120]);

%set the callback function of the button
%when the button is pressed, i want to initiate the changestate function

set(face.B1,'callback','changestate(face,states,1);');

% while 1
    uiwait(fig)
% end

end
```

this is the function that i want to call when the button is pressed. the contents of this function are not important to my question, but i include it just in case

```
function face = changestate(face,states,nextstate)

disp('enter changestate')
    face.B1=set(face.B1,'string',states{nextstate}.B1str,'callback','changestate(face,states,states{nextstate}.B1next)');

if ~isnan(states(nextstate).B2str)
    face.B2=set(face.B2,'string',states{nextstate}.B2str,'callback','changestate(face,states,states{nextstate}.B2next)','visible','on');
else face.B2=set(face.B2,'visible','off');
end

if ~isnan(states(nextstate).B3str)
    face.B3=set(face.B3,'string',states{nextstate}.B3str,'callback','changestate(face,states,states{nextstate}.B3next)','visible','on');
else face.B3=set(face.B3,'visible','off');
end

face.txtbx=set(face.txtbx,'string',states{nextstate}.txtbxstr);
%     uiresume(fig)
end
```

the error that i am receiving is:

Error using waitfor
Undefined function or variable 'face'.

Error using waitfor
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

this error occurs when i press the button B1. I want the button to initiate the changestate function. can someone explain to me why i am getting this error?

Comment: thank you werner. my code is now working

Comment: You are welcome. Please, accept the answer clicking on the green check near my answer. Don't forget that if you want to notify the person that answer your question you need to comment on its answer, otherwise the person won't know you have commented. I also noticed that you havent accepted answer for your other questions, please, if you are satisfied with the answers, make sure to mark them as accepted. x)

Answer (score 1):

When you use string declaration for a callback, it will be evaluated at the workspace callback scope. If you want your function to be evaluated with the variables at the current scope you should use one of the following:

```
…,'callback',@(~,~) changestate(face,states,states{nextstate}.B1next),...
…,'callback',@(hObj,evt) changestate(hObj,evt,face,states,states{nextstate}.B1next),...
…,'callback',{@changestate,face,states,states{nextstate}.B1next),...
```

instead of:

```
...,'callback','changestate(face,states,states{nextstate}.B1next),...
```

Where in the second and third callbacks, your function should be able to retrieve two more arguments, that are the button handle (`hObj`), and event data (`evt`), which will probably be empty.

The reason is the following, [quoting here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011b/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-55506.html):

> When MATLAB evaluates **function handles**, the same variables are in
>   scope as when the function handle was created. (In contrast, callbacks
>   specified as strings are evaluated in the base workspace.) This
>   simplifies the process of managing global data, such as object
>   handles, in a GUI.

Whereas when you use string:

> Setting a callback property to a string causes MATLAB to **evaluate that
>   string** in the base workspace **when the callback is invoked**.

As you used `uiwait`, execution stops inside `uiwait (line 82)` (for my matlab version), which has a `waitfor` command, giving the following error:

```
Error using waitfor
Undefined function or variable 'face'.
```

If you don't use a `uiwait`, it would evaluate the string callback at the global workspace, and the error would look like:

```
>> Undefined function or variable 'face'.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389240/getting-matlab-handles-events-or-properties) may also be of your interest.