# Matlab gui WindowButtonMotionFcn crashes when called too often?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, hover, matlab-guide

I've set `WindowButtonMotionFcn` to my callback which plots three plots, with the data depending on mouse position. However this seems to be too much for MATLAB to handle, because after moving my mouse around a bit, the GUI stops responding.

I use this code (copied parts from someone):

```
set(handles.figure1, 'windowbuttonmotionfcn', @hover_Callback);

function hover_Callback(hObject, handles, eventdata)
inside = false;

pos = get(handles.axes1, 'currentpoint');
xlim = get(handles.axes1, 'XLim');
ylim = get(handles.axes1, 'YLim');

if (pos(1,1) > max(xlim(1), 1) && ...
        pos(1,1) < xlim(2) && ...
        pos(1,2) > ylim(1) && ...
        pos(1,2) < ylim(2))
    inside = true;
end
if ~inside
    return
end
ix = round(pos(1,1));
iy = round(pos(2,2));
axes(handles.axes2); cla; plot(squeeze(t2(ix,iy,:)), squeeze(d2(ix,iy,:)));
axes(handles.axes3); cla; plot(squeeze(t3(ix,iy,:)), squeeze(d3(ix,iy,:)));
axes(handles.axes4); cla; plot(squeeze(t4(ix,iy,:)), squeeze(d4(ix,iy,:)));
```

This causes my GUI to stop responding, without error codes. If I then quit it and start it again the whole of MATLAB stops responding. Anyone knows what could be happening and how I can fix this? Maybe I'm somehow clogging my memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a callback is called with high frequency, there is the danger that it will be called again before another call has finished executing (i.e. [re-entrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)). With [`WindowButtonMotionFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html#WindowButtonMotionFcn), there's a pretty darn good chance that this will happen.

You can prevent callback re-entrancy by inspecting the function call stack (the output of [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html)) for multiple calls to the responsible callback.  A very straightforward, but clever implementation of such a check called `isMultipleCall` is presented [in a post on undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-callback-re-entrancy/). The idea is to count the number of times the callback function name appears on the stack. Take the actual function directly from undocumentedmatlab.com, but it distills to the following:

```
function flag=isMultipleCall()
s = dbstack();
% s(1) corresponds to isMultipleCall
if numel(s)<=2, flag=false; return; end
% compare all functions on stack to name of caller
count = sum(strcmp(s(2).name,{s(:).name}));
% is caller re-entrant?
if count>1, flag=true; else flag=false; end
```

The usage of `isMultipleCall` is very simple. Put run it at the top of the callback (in this case, `hover_Callback`), and bail out if it indicates that multiple calls are in progress:

```
function hover_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if isMultipleCall();  return;  end

...

end
```

This prevents the callback from executing fully again until previous calls have terminated. Only the check will be run, skipping the intensive graphics object operations (i.e. `axes`, `plot`, etc.)

---

An **[alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117425/2778484)** is to use a [listener](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/continuous-slider-callback/#Event_Listener) for the `WindowButtonMotionEvent`:

```
handles.motion = handle.listener(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionEvent',@hover_callback2);
```

Then in the callback, check the `eventdata.CurrentPoint` property instead of `currentpoint`. Check for re-entrancy as above.

If you are NOT using GUIDE and do not have a `handles` structure managed by `guidata`, then call the listener something like `motionListener` and use `setappdata` to store the listener. For example,

```
setappdata(hFigure,'mouseMotion',motionListener);
```

Just use the known handle of any object in the GUI [so the listener persists](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/udd-events-and-listeners/#listener). You could also use `UserData` instead of setappdata, or [any other way of managing GUI data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065967/2778484).

---

As an aside, note that the `axes` command is rather slow, and can be avoided by passing the axis handle to `plot` directly:

```
plot(handles.axes2, squeeze(t2(ix,iy,:)), squeeze(d2(ix,iy,:)));
```

Comment: @Leo Your welcome. I'm glad it worked -- I wasn't sure if that would do it.

Comment: It was instant bug-relief :)