# MATLAB - GINPUT function without waitforbuttonpress

Tags: matlab, user-interface, user-controls, real-time-updates

I am creating a simulation GUI with MATLAB, using figure / plot to display current situation and interact with it through plot. I want to make it Real-time like program. So it is in like an infinite loop. I am using Ginput for mouse input but still want to make program running without waiting for click. How can I do that?

Comment: No, I am not looking for multiple calls, i am looking for how can my code resume without waiting for an input from mouse pointer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769249/matlab-how-to-get-the-current-mouse-position-on-a-click-by-using-callbacks) is what you want I suppose.

Comment: @Parag Yeah, I think you are right. I read the question as wanting to get points without a click at all, which would call for [`WindowButtonMotionFcn`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427388/matlab-gui-windowbuttonmotionfcn-crashes-when-called-too-often), but the goal is actually just to have the GUI continue to function while waiting for the click. So for that, `WindowButtonDownFcn` would be just the ticket. Good call.